# slope in model different value than slope in stand alone script

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, slope

When running slope(analysis) from model I receive a high value of somewhere around 71. After then exporting model as python snippet and changing only the output raster name (using same input raster) I receive a high value of 45 in the output raster.  This makes absolutely no sense.  Has anybody ever experienced this?

Comment: Could one value be slope percentage and the other degrees?

Comment: Thats a good thought. But no this came after literally just exporting snippet and changing output file name. Should both be degree?

Comment: Wait... I ask questions too early! Changing cell size environment in the model seemed to have fixed the problem.

Comment: Okay, thank you for sharing that information! In order to bring a good close to this thread, I will redirect it to another one in which the effect of cell size on slope calculations is documented (even though the question asked there is different).